# Nodejs Follow User

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is my User model:**

```
    let mongoose = require("mongoose");

    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username:{
            type:String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        email:{
            type:String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password:{
            type:String,
            required: true
        },
        profile:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        follower:[{
            type: String,
        }]
      });

  let User= module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This is my app.js:

```
app.post('/metin/:id/', function(req, res){
User.findById(req.user

).exec(function(err, user){
console.log(user);

User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, friend){
console.log(friend)
if(err){
console.log(err);
}
User.update(user,{$push: { follow: friend }}, function(err){
  if(err){
console.log(err);
}else{
res.send('Success');
}
});
});
});
```

Guys as you can see:
**user** is the user which is current user(Which presses on follow button)

**friend** is the user which wrote the article.

What I do is: I take the current user information from **user** and I get the information of **article author** by friend.

I tried to use **$push** to implement it.

But why that it is not working? Can someone tell/help me?

When I click to follow button I get the error of:

> at new CastError
>   (C:\Users\agul\Desktop\ZaibJS\zaibjs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
>   . . .
>    'Cast to string failed for value "

It happens here : at path "follower"

Edit solution:
By the helps of Sivaraj P(Thanks).
I changed my model(follower part):

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
.
.
.
    follower:[{
            type: ObjectId,
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{$push: { follow: friend }}`

here **friend is an object and not a string**. So you are getting the cast error.

Two possible ways you can resolve this:

1, you can change the type of follower to `{}` if you really want to store the whole friend object (which is not a good practice).

2, you can change the type of follower to ObjectId and set the objectId of friend to follower field(recommended practice)